# Python file.read() doesn't return full contents (Flaky)

Tags: python

Roughly speaking, I'm calling the following function twice in a row:

```
def _read_bytes(path):
    with open(path, "rb") as f:
        print(f"f.tell() (should always be 0): {f.tell()}")
        s = f.read()
        print(f"f.read(): {s}")
        print(f"f.tell() (should be length of file): {f.tell()}")
        print(f"f.seek(0, 2) (should be length of file): {f.seek(0, 2)}")
        return s
```

We're seeing a flake in CI where running this twice results in the following output:

```
# first time
f.tell() (should always be 0): 0
f.read(): b'PAR1\x15\x00\x15\x0e......' # 1109 bytes long
f.tell() (should be length of file): 1109
f.seek(0, 2) (should be length of file): 1109

# second time
f.tell() (should always be 0): 0
f.read(): b'PAR1\x15\x00\x15\x0e......' # 10585 bytes long
f.tell() (should be length of file): 10585
f.seek(0, 2) (should be length of file): 10585
```

The bytes in the first `f.read()` contains exactly the first 1109 bytes of the second `f.read()` call. The really odd thing about this is that `f.seek(0, 2)` returns different numbers each time. When might `f.seek(0, 2)` return different values on the same file?

Details:

- Python 3.9
- Running in Circle CI's machine-ubuntu image on an xlarge machine with parallelism turned on (8 CI nodes)

Comment: How do you know that `b'PAR1\x15\x00\x15\x0e......' # 10585 bytes long`?

Comment: Is the file in the middle of being created when you run this?

Comment: Maybe more bytes have been written to the file between the first and the second run?

Comment: un-indent the return statement so that is not *in* the `with`??

Comment: "How do you know that b'PAR1\x15\x00\x15\x0e......' # 10585 bytes long?" Technically I'm assuming this,  but what I do know for certain is that the first one is shorter than the second and is a prefix of the second — "Is the file in the middle of being created when you run this?" It shouldn't be. I'm using `pyarrow.parquet.write_table`, which uses a `ParquetWriter` in a `with` block —
 "Maybe more bytes have been written ..." See second answer — "un-indent the return statement so that is not in the with??" I don't see how that's relevant

Answer (score 1):

I forgot that I have multiple threads writing to the same file, so another thread might have cleared the file + partially written the file when the current thread is reading the file. *facepalm*

Solution was to use a file lock to ensure that only one thread writes + reads the file at a time.

Comment: You should never overwrite a file. Instead, write to a new file in the same directory, then rename over top of the old file. The `x` mode may be useful if new filenames might collide, or you could use the `tempfile` module.

Comment: @o11c: it was actually a requirement in our specific situation to use the same filepath because we needed to specify the same lock file; the problem was I needed to use a second lock file earlier. zkoza: This solved my specific question. I can elaborate more.